# C stdio.h no such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, gcc

`gcc` worked perfectly fine until I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 and now when I run:

```
gcc file.c
```

an error shows up:

```
file.c:1:18: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I checked if `stdio.h` was there and it still was in `/usr/include/stdio.h`. Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gcc-5.4
```

This reinstalls `gcc`. Reinstalling sometimes fixes problems.

Answer (score 27):

First run:

```
find /usr/include/ -name "stdio.h"
```

If no files are returned, run:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential
```

That will reinstall any missing files.

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential` fixed the error for me, thanks!

Comment: I added "-get" after "apt" to be "sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential", so that the computer executes the command successfully. Thank you. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

Install missing library:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

It was the same error in Xubuntu 22 in MPLAB. i fix it using

```
sudo apt-get install avr-libc
```

Answer (score 0):

Going into the C/C++ Configurations and adding `/usr/include/**` fixed it for me.

Comment: sorry, how to change C/C++ Configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the *View* tab if you are using VSCode. Search for C/C++ edit configuration(UI). Copy/paste these paths to the *include path* section of the configuration.

```
/usr/include/
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include/linux
/usr/include/c++/9/tr1
/usr/include/c++/9
```

You have to paste these paths.

Save your `.c` file and run it as `gcc /path` in terminal.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Could you also please add a couple of screenshots to make it easier for users to find and apply this setting?